# Inequality Graph Behavior

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let there be $\frac{(x-2)(x-4)}{x(x-1)}\leq 0$

the answer is $0<x<1$ or $2\leq x\leq4$


I understand that the way to find the solution is to look for the numbers that set to zero the right hand side and than to look at numbers between each one.
If you draw a X axis it will always result a sequence of $+$ and $-$, why does it happened? (there will never be a situation of $-$ $-$ or $+$ $+$ in a row), is it due to the behavior of those inequality (polynomial?)?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions, then $\frac fg$ can only change sign either because $f = 0$ or $g = 0$. So continuity is important here, not the polynomial shapes of the functions.

Comment: You will get "++" or "--" if have have roots of even multiplicity in numerator or denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not defined if $x\in\{0,1\}$.

For other values, it is $\le 0$ iff 1 or 3 of the following are true (a product of terms is negative iff an odd number of factors are negative):
$$
x \le 0\\
x \le 1\\
x \le 2\\
x \le 4\\
$$

For compatibility reasons, this is possible only on the intervals
$$
[0,1], [2,4]
$$
The set of solutions is obtained excluding the two values where $f$ is not defined.